# Automatically running CMD after python script running::

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I have a python script and would like to open CMD and run another exe app after finishing with python script..
I have been trying to use os system and subprocess and read the forum, however can not find how to run another .exe app in the cmd
I got the following rror:
command is not recognized as an internal or external command operable ...
I attached the script:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import subprocess
import sys


 L_b          =          int(input("PLEASE ENTER LENGTH OF BEAM: "))                                                                              
 xf           =          L_b+3
 print(xf)
 p = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "NAMEOFAPP.exe",shell = True)
 #p = subprocess.call(["NAMEOFAPP"], shell = True)
 #os.system("start /B start NAMEOFAPP.exe @cmd /k {NAMEOFAPP.exe}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/path/to/the/file") ## Do this if you're not currently in the directory that contains the .exe file
os.system("start NAMEOFAPP.exe") ## This command runs the app
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).